# Different ways to initialize a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

As far as I know, there are 4 ways to declare a dictionary in Swift:

```
var dict1: Dictionary<String, Double> = [:]
var dict2 = Dictionary<String, Double>()
var dict3: [String:Double] = [:]
var dict4 = [String:Double]()
```

It seems these four options yields the same result.

What's the difference between these?

Comment: ahh my bad I am sorry

Comment: @EricD Thank you so much for the guidelines I will take care next time.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All you're doing is noticing that you can:

- Use explicit variable typing, or let Swift infer the type of the variable based on the value assigned to it.
- Use the formal specified generic struct notation `Dictionary<String,Double>`, or use the built-in "syntactic sugar" for describing a dictionary type `[String:Double]`.

Two times two is four.

And then there are in fact some possibilities you've omitted; for example, you *could* say

```
var dict5 : [String:Double] = [String:Double]()
```

And of course in real life you are liable to do *none* of these things, but just assign an *actual* dictionary to your variable:

```
var dict6 = ["howdy":1.0]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and give more examples.